# Can you send a dynamic template to a list, using only list id?

Tags: c#, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3, sendgrid-templates

According to the SendGrid docs, it seems like I can send a template to a list by inputting the template ID and list ID into the [singlesend](https://sendgrid.api-docs.io/v3.0/single-sends/create-single-send) call. However when I call this method with those JSON fields, I get an error.

JSON:
`{"sender_id":779461,"filter":{"list_ids":["572d0ae8-c665-4265-8e90-28fda56d9409"],"send_to_all":"false"},"template_id":"d-2b8c55e6e0a6463ab096d2e146d77c2c"}`

Error: `{
  "errors": [
    {
      "field": "",
      "message": "json could not be unmarshalled"
    }
  ]
}`

I've been trying to get the correct JSON format for a while now, with no luck due to this non-descriptive error. I am also using the C# library for .NET and I cannot find any methods to set a list id to the message. The SendGrid support portal is broken so I cannot reach out to them.

Answer (score 0):

try your json like this send_to_all is not of type string but boolean:

> {
>       "sender_id": 779461,
>       "filter": {
>           "list_ids": [
>               "572d0ae8-c665-4265-8e90-28fda56d9409"
>           ],
>           "send_to_all": false
>       },
>       "template_id": "REAL UUID"
>   }

Comment: can you check my edit template_id should be uuid format ?